# kotlin | start applications installed through adapter but intent return null

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, package-managers

I created an app that display the apps installed on my device
I want through the adapter to open any application when I click on it, but the value of intent prints it null and does not enter the function of starting the application

this part of my adapter

```
 class AdapterForApps(private var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForApps.AppsViewHolder>() {


        private var list: MutableList<App> = ArrayList()
    private var packs: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

        constructor(context: Context,packageManager: PackageManager): this(context) {
            val packageInfos = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
           val packageInf = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
            for (packageInfo in packageInf) {
                val appN = packageInfo.packageName
                packs.add(appN)
            }
            for (packageInfo in packageInfos) {
                val appName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager) as String
                if (appName.startsWith("com.", true)) {
                    continue
                }

                val appDrawable = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
                list.add(App(appName, appDrawable))

            }
        }
```

I put setonclicklistener on the app icon
like this

```
            val packageName=packs[position]
            holder.appName.text=list[position].name
            holder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(list[position].image)
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                println("$packageName name package")

                if (packageName!=null) {
                val intent=  context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)

                    print("intent is :$intent ")
                    if (intent != null)
                    {
                        context.startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is what is printed when I click on any application icon
[pic of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbA2q.png)

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? If it is Android 11 or higher, did you configure your app for [package visibility rules](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)?

Comment: @CommonsWare the version is 12

Comment: You have to manage package visibility

Comment: @primo but some apps still returns null in getlaunchintentforpackage(namePackage)
what queries for allow interact between app with all applications installed

Comment: you went through this link? https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring